# How we can achieve JSON to PCAP using Python or NodeJS?

Tags: python, node.js

I have one **pcap** file which I have converted to **JSON** and modified that JSON file. 
Now I want to convert it back to pcap file.

If any NodeJS or Python library can solve that then would be very much helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you looked at [pcapy](https://github.com/CoreSecurity/pcapy)?

Comment: Actually pcapy does not solve my purpose. I need to conver JSON file to PCAP file. any language is fine. We can port to other.